# Why do I get unauthorized access while using keyboard programmatically?

Tags: c#, uwp, keyboard, combinations, keycode

[image: Error image]

```
InputInjector inputInjector = InputInjector.TryCreate();
var shift = new InjectedInputKeyboardInfo();
shift.VirtualKey = (ushort)(VirtualKey.Shift);
shift.KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.None;

var tab = new InjectedInputKeyboardInfo();
tab.VirtualKey = (ushort)(VirtualKey.Tab);
tab.KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.None;
inputInjector.InjectKeyboardInput(new[] { shift, tab });
shift.KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.KeyUp;
tab.KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.KeyUp;
```

Please have look at this image and tell me what should i do to fix this problem

Comment: Please don't post images of code, instead [edit] your question to include your code (an [mcve]) as well as any input and desired output along any error messages you may or may not be getting

Comment: Code added, but please look at the image too.

Comment: Please always include the error message as text and not images too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.preview.injection.inputinjector.trycreate?view=winrt-19041) for the `InputInjector.TryCreate()` method, it says:

> **Note**: The APIs in this namespace require the inputInjectionBrokered restricted capability.

You need to update your [`Package.appxmanifest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/appx-package-manifest) to add the capability, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package
    ...
    xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
    IgnorableNamespaces="... rescap">
...
<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="inputInjectionBrokered"/>
</Capabilities>
</Package>
```

Comment: sorry i am noob, where should i paste this code?